# Attempting to override supportssecurecoding but doesn't compile

Tags: ios, swift, secure-coding

I'm converting older code to Swift 4 which uses SecureCoding.  Apple documentation says this is a requirement however my code doesn't compile.  I've tried changing the declarations between static, func, var, and class however none of these do the trick to convert to Swift 4.

Here is the code where I'm attempting to make the override:

```
 override public class func supportsSecureCoding() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

The error is shown saying method does not override any method from its superclass.  [Reference Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding/1855946-supportssecurecoding)

Here is the **full updated code which includes the solution**:

```
import CareKit

public class ZCCareMonthlySchedule : OCKCareSchedule  {

    var calendar: NSCalendar?

    public class func monthlyScheduleWithStartDate(startDate: NSDateComponents,  occurrencesFromJanuaryToDecember: [NSNumber], monthsToSkip: UInt, endDate: NSDateComponents?) -> ZCCareMonthlySchedule? {

        guard occurrencesFromJanuaryToDecember.count == 12
            else { return nil}

        //TODO: Requires fixing after CareKit is updated to handle sub classes

//        let schedule = super.initWithStartDate(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, occurrences: occurrencesFromJanuaryToDecember, timeUnitsToSkip: monthsToSkip)




        return nil

    }



    override public var type: OCKCareScheduleType {
        return OCKCareScheduleType.other
    }



    override public func numberOfEvents(onDate date: DateComponents) -> UInt {

        calendar = NSCalendar.init(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        calendar!.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")! as TimeZone


        let startMonth = calendar?.ordinality(of: NSCalendar.Unit.month, in: NSCalendar.Unit.era, for: self.startDate.date! )
        let endMonth = calendar?.ordinality(of: NSCalendar.Unit.month, in: NSCalendar.Unit.era, for: date.date! )
        let monthsSinceStart = startMonth! - endMonth!
        let month = calendar?.component(NSCalendar.Unit.month, from: date.date!)

        //TODO:  Add a unit test to verify this works
        let occurrences : UInt = ((UInt(monthsSinceStart) % (self.timeUnitsToSkip + 1)) == 0) ? self.occurrences[month!-1].uintValue : 0;

        return occurrences;
    }



    //MARK: NSSecureCoding Support


    override public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool{
        return true
    }

    required convenience public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        self.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    //MARK: NSCopying Support
    override public func copy(with zone: NSZone?) -> Any {

        let theCopy = super.copy(with: zone) as! ZCCareMonthlySchedule

        return theCopy
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your class or extension declaration where you adopt the protocol?  You don't use `override` with protocol adoption. It should be a `static var`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paulw11, the answer was to place this into a variable as a static var such as the following:

```
 override public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool{
        return true
    }
```